# Datatables not showing any rows on IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, datatables

Is this a known issue? I am able to see all columns on IE8 firefox and chrome but not IE7. there is no javascript error and pagination is working it showing 5 pages but not rows

Comment: What language? I don't think Javascript has that type, so maybe you're talking about C# or VB.NET?

Comment: something to do with CSS3/HTML5? IE7 is now old. Can u share a printscreen?

Comment: @Renan javascript. what do you mean javascript doesnt have that type?

Comment: @NewtonSheikh html 4 and css2

Comment: @user521180 I'm fairly sure it does not. Some Javascript frameworks may have that type, but it's not a pure Javascript type. If you're using a third party framework, please edit your question to include that framework in the tags.

Comment: maybe something to do with DOM in ie7. use ie development tools(f12) to inspect the element and check if the html elements are getting created. DOM rendering in ie7 is different from all other browsers.

Comment: @renan what type are we talking about here?

Comment: You say you're having problems with datatables. Datatables aren't something native to Javascript. I'm basically asking what is this Datatable you mention. Is is what you'd expect .NET's GridView control to render (.NET's got a type called [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx))? Do you mean the [jQuery plugin](http://www.datatables.net/)? Or is it something else?